# Can't connect my Samsung Note 3 Neo to Android Studio 3.1.3

Tags: android-studio, debugging, usb

After connecting my phone to my laptop, Android Studio still can't detect that device... What should I do? I have already enabled the developer option and switch on the usb debugging option on my phone...

Answer (score 0):

Try installing adb drivers, I used to have that issue with a motorola moto e, reinstalled drivers and it worked

https://developer.samsung.com/search/searchList.do?pageIndex=1&searchBigCategory=SD&searchSubCategory=&parSearchValue=adb+driver&pageReturnCheck=&pageSize=50&pageOrder=&searchInput=adb+driver

Comment: THAT works for detecting device, but my device API level lower than 20, so instant run is not supported in android studio... is there any way to solve this?